# @Input() in angular component

Tags: angular

I want to understand the internal working of `@Input` property's rendering.

If I define a component in Angular, where `type` and `title` are `@Input` properties, how does the component understand that type property's value is string (to be considered as-is) and title property's value is to be fetched from config file's component_title variable?

```
<my-component #comp [type]='CONFIRMATION' [title]='config.component_title'></my-component>
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I don't think `CONFIRMATION` in `[type]='CONFIRMATION'` is string, it will refer to `this.CONFIRMATION`

Comment: Wrap it as `[type]="'CONFIRMATION'"` in order to pass a string along

Comment: Ok, got it. My syntax error had my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `foo="bar"`, then `bar` is considered as a string. The string "bar" is thus passed as the value for the input `foo`.

If you use `[foo]="bar"`, then `bar` is considered as an angular expression. The value of the expression `bar` (so, in this case, the value of the property `bar` of the component) is thus passed as the value for the input `foo`.

From these two rules, you can thus deduce that `foo="bar"` is equivalent to `[foo]="'bar'"`.

Answer (score 1):

[type] = "'CONFIRMATION'" is used for string. (See the quotes)

Answer (score -2):

read this to find some solution for you

[https://toddmotto.com/passing-data-angular-2-components-input](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/passing-data-angular-2-components-input)

Comment: Not that I have downvoted your answer; but this is not really an answer to the specific question...